# How to send CTRL+S to MS Word?

Tags: c#

I am working on a program that auto saves a Microsoft Office document after specific time (loop).

On a click of a button it will activate timer and after a given time delay it should send `CTRL+S` to Word and save the document.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startTimer.Enabled = true;
    stratTimer.Start();
}

private void startTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.SendWait("^{s}");
    MessageBox.Show("doc auto saved");
}
```

The problem is that `SendKeys.Send("^{s}");` does not work.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Ever since Windows Vista, apps should not attempt to send keystrokes via message pump or other legacy means.  Look into Windows UI Automation instead

Comment: Additionally you can use _Visual Studio Tools for Office_ and use the .NET wrappers around the COM Automation model

Comment: What is your goal here?  Word already has an option to auto save at a specified interval.

Answer (score 0):

`SendKeys.SendWait` sends keystrokes to the currently active window, so the keystrokes can be received by other window, like browser (if you are viewing this answer while the automation exe is running in the background). It is not a wise idea to send key strokes to arbitrary window.

This can partially explain why your code does not work in some cases. And it has other issues.

Just as `MickyD`'s comment, don't use this "SendKeys" solution for automation nowadays. For auto save, [VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vsto/info) is the right way to go.

See [How to: Programmatically save documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-save-documents?view=vs-2017).